# How can one switch off the checkpoint notification?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm having the problem that I like my notebooks slimmer than is required to prevent an annoying temporary layout change caused by the display of the automatic checkpoint creation.

In this screenshot:

[image: GUI layout space for checkpoint creation notification]

one can see the empty space between the menu entry "Help" and the "Trusted" status icon.
This space is being used by the "Checkpoint created" notification that temporary pops up, with the interval of the automatic checkpoint creation.

Now, whenever the browser window is sufficiently slim, so that the

```
Checkpoint created <timestamp>
```

does not fit into this space, the layout manager temporarily creates a new line in the header, and the whole notebook is scrolling down one line, only to scroll up one line a few seconds later. I find this behavior highly annoying, so I would like Jupyter to do its checkpoints withOUT telling me about it. I really don't require this notification.
Is that possible to configure somehow?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like disabling two event handlers should achieve result you need. Just put code below in the first cell of your notebook

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.events.off('checkpoint_created.Notebook');
IPython.notebook.events.off('notebook_saved.Notebook');
```

I've found these handlers in code of jupyter notebook:

- [`checkpoint_created.Notebook`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/b8b66332e2023e83d2ee04f83d8814f567e01a4e/notebook/static/notebook/js/notificationarea.js#L352)
- [`notebook_saved.Notebook`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/b8b66332e2023e83d2ee04f83d8814f567e01a4e/notebook/static/notebook/js/notificationarea.js#L341)

### Creating a nbextension

If you require the behavior on all your notebook i suggest creating a simple nbextension.

First, create the extension directory under directory path you want:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/Documents/checkpoint_disable
```

Create `main.js` file in above dir

Contents of `main.js`:

```
define([
    'require',
    'jquery',
    'base/js/namespace',
], function (
    requirejs,
    $,
    Jupyter,
) {
    "use strict";

    var initialize = function () {
        Jupyter.notebook.events.off('checkpoint_created.Notebook');
        Jupyter.notebook.events.off('notebook_saved.Notebook');
        Jupyter.notebook.events.on(
            'notebook_saved.Notebook',
            function() {
                console.log('Notebook saved');
            })
    };

    var load_ipython_extension = function () {
        return Jupyter.notebook.config.loaded.then(initialize);
    };

    // return object to export public methods
    return {
        load_ipython_extension : load_ipython_extension
    };
});
```

> **NOTE** Disabling two mentioned event handlers affects only UI. Under the hood notebook is still being autosaved **if there is new content since last save**

### Installing nbextension

You need to use `jupyter-nbextension` command provided already with jupyter.

First install the extension

```
$ jupyter-nbextension install --user ~/Documents/checkpoint_disable
```

Next enable the extension

```
$ jupyter-nbextension enable checkpoint_disable/main
```

You can check that extension is installed by invoiking

```
$ jupyter-nbextension list
```

And you're done. The extension should load automatically.
You can verify that it is true if you see in browser javascript console log similar to one below:

> ```
> load_extensions 
> Arguments { 0: "jupyter-js-widgets/extension", 1: "checkpoint_disable/main", … }
> utils.js:60
> Loading extension: checkpoint_disable/main
> ```

#### Resources

- [Installing and enabling extensions](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/frontend_extensions.html#installing-and-enabling-extensions)
- [Custom front-end extensions](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/frontend_extensions.html#custom-front-end-extensions)
- [Enabling/Disabling extensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#enabling-disabling-extensions)

Comment: Well, to change ALL my notebooks I wouldn't call "just" ;) Isn't there a way to put this into `jupyter_notebook_config.py` ? I guess in the worst case, I could put it into the ipython_kernel config.

Comment: thanks so much, looks awesome. While trying to follow your instructions, I noticed that you **say** "extension directory under jupyter" but your mkdir is working inside the .ipython folder? Which one should it be?

Comment: `~/.jupyter/nbextensions/` for some reason did not work where `.ipython` did. I recommend that you check which one will load the extension on your installation.
I would be happy to put more detailed info but the i had difficulties finding good nbextension resources.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye I've found the docs on installing extension. It should be more straightforwad and relaible now.

Comment: your install commends returns this: "Please supply at least one subcommand: disable, enable, install, list, uninstall"

Comment: apparently it needs to be "install --user" not "--user install" (reverse order) ?

Comment: so, just to be sure, this only disables the event notification, not the actual checkpoint creation, right?

Comment: Yes i've put option in wrong order.

Exactly, only event notification is disabled, the checkpoint will still be periodically saved.

Comment: Hm, have you confirmed that? When I open the notebook it says that a checkpoint would be created every 120 s but I don't see that happening.

Comment: Yes i confirm that the notebook is saved every 120 seconds IF there is something new to change. To test that you have to open the notebook edit it and wait 2 minutes. Then you can check in file browser that `modified_date` on notebook `.ipynb`file was updated.
I've added a console logging So you will be able to see that notebook is being autosaved